# UITableview tries to scrollToTop but doesn't (Indicator tries to go up, strange.) - video

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I've been working on a UITableView and I can't hit the statusbar to scroll up, however it seems like it's trying to scroll up, but it doesn't.

Here you can see a video of it (Decided to use mp4 instead of GIF since it was so laggy)
http://i.gyazo.com/4c7be7437116e420411ac879b6d0d784.mp4

If you look at the video you can see that you indicator on the right side tries to scroll up but doesn't ? Has anyone experienced something similar ?

I'm also using `ECSlidingViewController`

My current code
Called upon `-viewDidLoad`

```
-(void)setTableViewStuff {

    [self.myTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    [self.myTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YouTubeTableCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


       self.myScrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    self.myTableView.scrollsToTop = YES;
}
```

Table View Code

```
#pragma mark - Table View



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 256;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return myVideoTitles.count;
}



// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    YouTubeTableCell *cell = (YouTubeTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if (cell == nil) {
        //cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        NSString* thumbnailURL = myVideoThumbnails[indexPath.row];
     [cell.myThumbnail setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[thumbnailURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] placeholderImage:nil];

    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

**EDIT**:
Found a solution to this!!, Apperiantely if you're using ECSlidingViewController you must have yourtableview.scrollstotop = NO; inside the "drawer"

Comment: We can't help without seeing your code. Are you modifying the contentInset or scrollIndicatorInsets on your table view? Anything in scrollViewDidScroll? Reloading table view cells?

Comment: I agree with @Brandon. In all probability _you_ are doing something that resets the scroll position. But you are not showing us what it is.

Comment: Added some code, sorry about that.

Comment: Instead of modifying your question to include the answer and changing the title to SOLVED, simply answer your own question (i.e. write an answer in the answer section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to this!!, Apperiantely if you're using ECSlidingViewController you must have yourtableview.scrollstotop = NO; inside the "drawer"

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. Can you please accept this as an answer ?

Comment: I must wait 1 day more.